# Keep path when user logout in FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.5

I'm using FOSUserBundle in an ongoing project and everything works fine but I'm having a small problem when I close session because I go to the index of the application instead of staying in the safe area (secured) which is `/admin/login` where the login form is. This is my `security.yml`:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:
                 path: /logout
                 target: /admin
                 invalidate_session: false
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

anyone can tell me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Maybe I didn't understood correctly but, is your login form "within" secured area?

Comment: @DonCallisto yes it's

Comment: So how can you login if login form itself is within secured area?

Comment: @DonCallisto I miss understood you completely at first, no, it's not at the secure area since then I can not login anytime, that what you see is my only configuration and because in the frontend I not need login access then I leave the other configuration out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the `anonymous: true`.  If you basically want the whole site to be under access control, with no pages apart from the login page being accessible to someone not logged in then you want something like this:

```
security:
        encoders:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

        role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

        providers:
            fos_userbundle:
                id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

        firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false
            main:
                pattern: ^/
                form_login:
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                    csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                logout:
                     path: /logout
                     target: /admin
                     invalidate_session: false
                anonymous: ~ # NO ANONYMOUS ACCESS

        access_control:
            - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
            # anonymous visitors need to be able to get to the logon pages
            - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } 
            - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            # Could also add "safe" routes like an "about" or "contact us" pages here if you like
            - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```